# Embedding Sat Nav into a web system

Tags: api, google-maps, embed, directions, satellite-navigation

I've been looking into embedding sat nav into a web system that can be used on the ipad, but not as an IOS app. It would be a web system with login. I've found plenty of options that will give me a map with markers at the start and destination however I'm trying to find something that will give me turn by turn directions.

I've looked at Google Maps and Waze, but I can only find something that will invoke the waze app or the Google maps app and not just let you embedd the sat nav straight into my system.

Free options are obviously better but options you have to pay for are not out of the question.

I'm just wondering if someone out there has done this before or knows of an API I can tap into to achieve this.

Comment: Depending on exactly what you're planning on doing I believe Google's terms of service forbids it's API to be used for turn-by-turn navigation.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) will give you the start and end points along with a number of 'legs' along the route which you can use to roll your own version of a 'sat nav' system, the turn by turn navigation however is not built in (likely to encourage users to rely on Google native app).

The API returns [a number of routes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#DirectionsResponseElements) which you can plot, and provides 'steps' (modular directions units, e.g. turn left at such and such street) to allow for almost full functionality. The only thing you would have to implement yourself would be tracking the user as they follow the route using geolocation and then updating the users position and current step as you go along.